# does gcutil addsnapshot replace existing ones?

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot, gcutil

The documentation states that `gcutil` `addsnapshot` will create a new snapshot.

My question is:
If a snapshot with the same name already exists, will it replace that snapshot?

Comment: I see that Google Compute support differential snapshots.  If addsnapshot is called a second time with the same name, presumably it will update the existing snapshot with the changes? is this correct? If I create a new snapshot with a different name based on the same disk, will I be charged for the change in data only? From a cost standpoint, does it matter if I use different names for each snapshot, as opposed to using a single snapshot name?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old case, I'll try to answer it:

No, it won't replace that snapshot. The snapshot cannot be updated. You need to choose another name or you will get the following error message:

```
ERROR: RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXISTS: The resource 'projects/<project>/global/snapshots/<snapshot>' already exists
```

Regarding your questions in the comment, new snapshots are created based on previous snapshots.

I'm not totally sure but I think that you are charged for the number of GB you see in the Developers Console in the 'SIZE' column. Right now, every GB costs $0.124 per month as you can see at https://cloud.google.com/compute/#pricing

Regards